# Using charlist wildcard in the middle of the string

Tags: sql, wildcard

I'm trying to run a query where the `charlist wildcard` is defined in the middle of the string as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key LIKE 'A___[AB]________',
```

and of course it doesn't work. Here I want to query for 13 letters string which consists of 'A' at the beginning, and 'A' or 'B' at the 6th place. I do not want to use the keyword `"OR"` for this search since later I have to run more complicated queries, and I want to keep it simple.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which dbms? [AB] is not traditional ANSI SQL like, perhaps you should check out regexp?

Comment: What rdbms are you using? I have successfully tested it in SQL-Server 2005.

Comment: You can also do substring and check 1:st and 6:th character separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` does not understand regular expresions in *Oracle*. use `REGEXP_LIKE` instead. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

your regexp should look like this `'^A.{4}[AB].{7}$'`